# Deserialize a SecureString saved as text in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, securestring

PowerShell can store a value securely in a file:

```
PS > Read-Host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File ~\Desktop\SerializedSecurePassword.txt
```

How does one deserialize the value stored in the text into a `System.Security.SecureString` in a C# application?

```
string path = @"C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\SerializedSecurePassword.txt";
string contents = File.ReadAllText(path);

System.Security.SecureString SecurePassword = ?;
```

Comment: You can use `ConvertTo-SecureString` from C# or the [`ProtectedData.Unprotect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh68ketz(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The latter will require you to parse the input string manually

Comment: I used the technique suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871337/how-can-i-encrypt-user-settings-such-as-passwords-in-my-application#8875545).

Comment: I think in this case you can use "System.Security.Cryptography" and "ProtectedData.Unprotect()" method for this.

Comment: @craig post that as an answer then