# Mobile equivalent of System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8874634/132599) I use `System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` to encrypt a string on Windows. Is there an equivalent for iOS and Android, i.e. a certificate associated with the device/user that could be used to encrypt a string so I don't have to make up a key or certificate myself?

Comment: In iOS , you are not allowed to identify a user by the device or any device identifier at all, it is against the policy. You should instead create a UUID and save that as a reference. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936371/how-to-identify-ios-device-uniquely-instead-of-using-uuid-and-udid

Comment: In Android you can use KeyChain for this