# LINQ ignores case

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have following LINQ statement:

```
(from o in Table where (o.Username == username && o.Password == password) select o).SingleOrDefault()
```

it seems that this ignores Case. how do I make sure that "Test" != "test" etc.
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your SqlServer is not case insensitive?

Comment: Also, please don't ever store passwords in the database.  At the very least, store a password hash, retrieve the record based on username and compare hashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ is not ignorning the case, its the SQL Server. Change the COLLATION to make SQL Server case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

As per Klaus's comment, the problem is likely to be your SQL server CI setting

However, it is bad practice to store passwords cleartext in any event - you should look at [hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883371/effective-password-encryption), or even better, use a security framework (like ASP.NET [Membership](http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/)) to manage these for you.

Comment: Also generally Username should be case insenstive while password is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

What LINQ provider are you using?  It matters.  E.g. LINQ to XML is case sensitive and you have to do ToUpperVariant() calls to become case insensitive and on SQL the behavior can vary based on sql collation settings.