# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\

Tags: php

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQRYn.png)i'm facing a syntax problem with my php code, can anyone please tell me where is the error ? thanks

```
 $requete = "SELECT count(*) FROM Utilisateur where 
    Nom_utilisateur = '".$username."' and mot_de_passe = '".$password."' ";
```

Comment: [Please, whatever you do, have a read up on SQL injections.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: look like some of values are ''

Comment: @thordarson thanks , i will.

Comment: Look like a valid expression to me. Are you sure is the place, the error occurs?

Comment: If you are using plain text passwords please stop that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197417/why-are-plain-text-passwords-bad-and-how-do-i-convince-my-boss-that-his-treasur

Comment: @stickybit yes i'm sure, should i use prepared statements maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Prepared statements would be better for multiple reasons, but the error doesn't appear to be related to the code presented.

Comment: i added a picture of my code in _komodo IDE_

Comment: Given by your screenshot, you're missing a ' after localhost, line 9. It's sometimes good to look at the color highlighting in your code editor. Wherever the colors start going off or the highlighting stops working there's probably a parsing error.

Comment: @mery: Yes you should use prepared statements in general as you've been told already. Is the error message giving you a line number? And this is the line? Be aware that the actual error mustn't necessarily be on that line. It's just the line the parser gets something unexpected. It might be unexpected for it because something some lines above did make it "think" like that.

Comment: @thordarson you're right thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 9 `$db_host = 'localhost;` you don't have closing `'`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this correct. I think you have something written wrong your varaible name. Please check everthing carefully. You can also write {$username} instead of " ' . . ' "

Comment: thank you, it was an error in the line 9, it works now.

Comment: that was your love to share with us!!