# I can't update data from firebase because of the random given character

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase i don't know how to enter or get that path in firebase and i want to change the password inside that random character

[image: my database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a specific value in the database, you must know the full path to that value.

If you know the email address, but not the key that email address, you can use a query to look up all child nodes of `users` with that email address.

```
let query = firebase.database.ref("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("gagfa@john.com");
```

Then you can load the data matching this query, iterate over the results (as there can be multiple) and update the property:

```
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
    userSnapshot.ref.child("password").set("CorrectHorseBatteryStaple");
  });
});
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but please read [Why are plain text passwords bad, and how do I convince my boss that his treasured websites are in jeopardy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197417/why-are-plain-text-passwords-bad-and-how-do-i-convince-my-boss-that-his-treasur) and reconsider storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: YO MAN I LOVE YOU ;* Thank you! xD

Comment: Hi Frank, is it necessary to store the password in Realtime Database?