# How to provide validation for the users model in views itself in django(not the custom user model)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having user model in the models.py and the every user even the repeated user emails and usernames are being stored in the database but I need the validation of email and password upto 8 characters in the views.py
My models.py is

```
class users(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goal = models.ManyToManyField(goals)
    style = models.ManyToManyField(designs)
```

My views.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        room = request.POST['room']
        g=goal=request.POST['goal']
        g = g.split(',')
        s=style=request.POST['style']
        s=s.split(',')
        user = users(password=password,email=email)
        user.room=rooms.objects.get(pk=room)
        goal = goals.objects.filter(pk__in=g)
        style = designs.objects.filter(pk__in=s)
        user.save()
        user.goal.add(*goal)
        user.style.add(*style)
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

My template is:

```
<div class="card-body">
              <form action="{% url 'car:user_register' %}" method="POST"  >
              {% csrf_token %}

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="room" id="name" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="hidden" name="goal" id="goal" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="hidden" name="style" id="style" value=" ">
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: if you are using forms, you can use min_length.

Comment: No @ sandeep I am using models and templates can you for this how?

Comment: can you show template

Comment: use "EmailField()" for emails in model. and also, use set_password to save password.

Comment: Ya @ sandeep I had added my template

Comment: I have write answer..Please clear following 1) "username" is not in model, but you are saving it in view. 2) "room, goal, style" is hidden. How will you get these in view.

Comment: yes room,goal,style are coming

Comment: yes username i had deleted

Comment: @ sandeep now can you say it

Comment: Can you please provide the url for your site, so I make a note to NEVER EVER create an account there ? (hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197417)