# Login page accepts only first 8 characters from the password as valid characters.

Tags: .net, forms, passwords

In a .net application I am working on, In the login page, the passowrd box takes only the first 8 characters to validate. When I enter anything starting from 9th character and I am still successfuly logged in.

It makes no difference if the password is 8 or more characters long. Still I only need to enter first 8 characters right and then I can enter anything  want.

1st Example
- If the user sets his password to Machine1
- in the login page these passwords are accepted: Machine158, Machine1&5552  etc.

2nd Example
- user sets his password to Wonderland-88 (in 'forgotten password' screen)
- in the login page these passwords are accepted:  Wonderlandy1, Wonderlanguage, Wonderlady-&1a etc.

This is definitely wrong. Only a correct password should be accepted. This is a .aspx page.

Please suggest me where would be the problem for this issue and how can I rectify this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please suggest me where would be the problem for this issue and how can I rectify this..

- Storing a plaintext password in a VARCHAR(8) field.
- Storing SomeFunction(LEFT(password,8)) or even just LEFT(password,8)
- Someone figured out how to use ancient crypt() functionality in .NET
- Dave wrote his own code to store passwords.

To really investigate, you'll need to track down in the code just what happens when users submit the username/password.

To rectify, first read [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623) - though a lot of it may be refresher for you.

After that, if you want to use a pure .NET Framework function, see [my answer to Is there a built in function to hash passwords in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21900427/1967612), which boils down to: Use [RFC2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a random salt of 8-16 bytes (stored in plaintext) and as many iterations as you can.  This is PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1.

If you're ok using a slight variant on a .NET Framework function, you can look at a fork of Jither's code at [my github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-CSharp-DeriveBytes-custom-A) which allows for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 or PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-384, both of which use 64-bit operations that reduce the advantage attackers with 2014 vintage GPU's have over defenders with 64-bit CPU based systems.

You can also try to find a .NET implementation of BCrypt or SCrypt, though be sure you trust it or test it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is, that an unsafe hash function is used to hash the passwords. Maybe the application uses DES hashing (crypt function) that would explain the 8 characters.

If this algorithm is used, you should switch to a slow key derivation function like [PBKDF2](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode) or [BCrypt](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/) instead. To find the relevant code, don't forget to search in SQL statements, hashing is often done there, even if it would be better placed in code.