# Salting and hashing the user submitted data

Tags: php, html, salt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

I have:

```
$insert_query = 'insert into '.$this->tablename.'(
        name,
        email,
        username,
        password,
        confirmcode
        )
        values
        (
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['name']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['email']) . '",
        "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['username']) . '",
        "' . md5($formvars['password']) . '",
        "' . $confirmcode . '"
        )';
```

I would like to salt and properly sha256 hash the password instead of using md5, how would I salt it properly? Is it secure enough to save the salt pass in the php file?

Comment: Hint, search for bcrypt :)

Comment: This more general approach may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: Or, search for any phrase containing "salt" and "hash", really. I would down-vote if I had any dailies left. Please *search first*, especially for such basic knowledge questions.

Comment: (*SHA-x, even with salt, is not appropriate for password hashes*. But this would have been turned up time and time again in a *search* ..)

Comment: @Jack What is the first number in the PasswordHash function? Looks like this: PasswordHash(8, FALSE)

Comment: Since this probably be closed, you could check [one my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) that deals with both hashing and encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can salt it properly by creating a random number and encrypting that.  One login system I did a while back actually encrypted the password via MD5, then generated a random number between 100,000 and 999,999 and added that onto the end of the encrypted password.  After that, the entire string was encrypted again via MD5.  Perhaps a bit overkill really, but it did the job certainly.

[You can read more on password salting, hashing, and encryption here.](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: It probably decreased the security of the initial MD5...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I agree.  Why do you say that?

Comment: So, the link is relevant (and this should be closed as a duplicate) .. but where does the rest fit in? (Also, hashing is *not* encryption.)

Comment: That's not overkill, that's underkill. MD5 is a very bad choice for hashing passwords, you should use a **slow** key-derivation function like BCrypt instead. What you did is security by obscurity, this helps only as long as an attacker has not gained any priviledges on the server. You could do the same easier adding a secret pepper.

Comment: Your scheme actually seems to have a name _vBulletin_ (there is currently a question open on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7229/8343)). With common hardware one can calculate 2 Giga such hashes per second, that makes about 2 milliseconds for a whole english dictionary. Thought you could be interested, won't bother you anymore :-).