# Encrypt sensitive data in PHP

Tags: php, security

I'm working on insecure cryptographic storage.  As I know to prevent this I have to encrypt my data.  All documents say that MD5 is weak,so can you suggest me some strong encryption in PHP,or I have to create my own encryption logic/scheme ?

Thks for all helps :)

Comment: encrypt or hash ? do not mix up . hash is 1-way . cannot get back the information . MD5 is a hash function .

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10945097/188331

Comment: Oh dear god the english. Anyways as said above you want to hash things like passwords, not encrypt them. MD5 is a hash but people have found ways to break it using rainbowtables and such. If you really want to have a good one you should use something like Blowfish with a really long salt.

Comment: chaining multiple MD5 & SHA1 is a quick solution.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: No; it isn't.

Comment: The OP doesn't even mention what data he wants to encrypt.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Salt Hashing** + **Sha**

```
// define your encryption key

$encyption_key = 'IMHPU7GG3HI5FCMYCT354P7V8FEUPRFL'; //sample


// Appending salt to the password
$_POST['pword'] .= $encryption_key;

// then Return the SHA-1 encryption
$password = sha1($_POST['pword']);
```

Comment: @lemondrop this will be just a sample in case it would be a registration for users :)

Comment: @Dagon oh my golly goose.. sorry for that.. lmao

Comment: How is this encryption?

Comment: @MathieuImbert just get it from my bunch of snippets  created in codeigniter for password hashing is this wrong? I used it before..

Comment: In this example, `$encyption_key` is a salt, not an encryption key, and the code implements hashing, not encryption.

Comment: @Kaii My point exactly. It is hashing, not encryption. The OP didn't mention anything about password hashing, except for a vague not about MD5.

Comment: @Kaii Imo its better to use random salts for each individual hash then use blowfish's weird system to validate them

Comment: thumbs up your all right.sorry for that.! just suggesting this would be a good idea

Comment: And anyway, if the OP *was* talking about password hashing, sha1 is just a little less weak than md5. BCrypt is a better fit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php