# How to secure a password field without putting too much burden on the end user

Tags: php, html, sql, encryption, passwords

I'm building a login interface for an e-commerce website and part of it is a password field.

I wonder how many characters are recommended as a minimum required that will be secure enough but will not be too heavy on the user?

Also, what will be the best decrypted way to use? (MD5 or others)

Comment: Use bcrypt to hash your passwords and the minimum length becomes less of an issue. Personally I enforce 6 chars minimum - but the fact that I've just given you my personal opinion should show why I'm voting to close this as Not Constructive. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097)

Comment: @Jack: encryption != hashing. You hash passwords, not encrypt them.

Comment: Instead of a "minimum required" field, why not use a weak-medium-strong indicator? That way you don't get in the way of a sale, but do reward good password behavior.

Comment: To store the password, [use bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). The password length is IMO mostly irrelevant: `zR2@1!` will probably be more secure than `password123` even if it's much shorter.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha My answer also discusses hashing of passwords. So I'm advertising my answer a little ... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use your suggestion in my website.

Comment: If you're handling people's money, and you're not an expert in this field, please consider using an existing framework for managing user accounts rather than writing your own - usercake, PEAR, whatever. This is a very expensive area to make mistakes in...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm using CodeIgniter.