# php mysql generate,store and match password and salt

Tags: php, salt

I have a file named pbkdf2.php.

```
<?php
/*
 * Password hashing with PBKDF2.
 * Author: havoc AT defuse.ca
 * www: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm
 */

// These constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
    // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" . 
        base64_encode(pbkdf2(
            PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
            $password,
            $salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
            PBKDF2_HASH_BYTES,
            true
        ));
}

function validate_password($password, $good_hash)
{
    $params = explode(":", $good_hash);
    if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
       return false; 
    $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    return slow_equals(
        $pbkdf2,
        pbkdf2(
            $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
            $password,
            $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
            (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
            strlen($pbkdf2),
            true
        )
    );
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
    $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
    {
        $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
    }
    return $diff === 0; 
}

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
?>
```

that I was downloaded it from [here](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

and I use it as below :

```
$password = "mypass";
$salt = "K3HtAz[|U8]Of9@?Ppj";
$hash = pbkdf2("SHA256", $password, $salt, 1, 20);
```

I've read some articles but couldn't help me to write one for me

I need to generate password and salt in user registration level and store them into MySQL and when user want to login , match them with user input in login form..

Comment: See [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) on how to do this with Bcrypt instead; it results in a single field for both salt and hashed password.

Comment: Thanks.I'm reading :)

Comment: This is the best article that I've read read so far... thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should use this code to generate :

```
$password = 'my password';
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(18)), '+', '.');
$pwhash = crypt($password, sprintf('$2y$%02d$%s', 13, $salt));
```

And match it by this method :

```
$given_password = $_POST['password']; // the submitted password
$db_hash = $row['Password']; // field with the password hash

$given_hash = crypt($given_password, $db_hash);

if (isEqual($given_hash, $db_hash)) {
    // user password verified
}

// constant time string compare
function isEqual($str1, $str2)
{
    $n1 = strlen($str1);
    if (strlen($str2) != $n1) {
        return false;
    }
    for ($i = 0, $diff = 0; $i != $n1; ++$i) {
        $diff |= ord($str1[$i]) ^ ord($str2[$i]);
    }
    return !$diff;
}
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) tutorial