# equivalent of MySQL's hex(aes_encrypt)

Tags: php, mysql

In mySql I do, `hex(AES_ENCRYPT('mytext','mykeystring'))`. This gives me a string with characters, rather than some unreadable things.

How can I do something like this in php? Is there a built in function that'll let me do this? Just like mySql has `hex` and `aes_encrypt` with a `password/salt`.

I'm not looking for exact aes encryption in php. Anything that returns a string of alphabets and numbers and that isnt easy to crack will do (has salt)

Comment: Try googling for an AES library implemented for PHP: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=php+aes However, you'll have to study MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT to learn 1) what cipher block chaining mode it is using 2) how it converts passwords into keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP equivalent is:

```
// MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT uses Rijndael 128 with ECB mode
$enc_text = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
// HEX() equivalent
echo bin2hex($enc_text);
```

Note that ECB block mode ain't great, and it's better to use CFB. My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) discusses this in more detail.

Comment: In your old post, there's a guy who's written twice `You should not use ECB either, for that matter`. If this should not be used, then what should be?

Comment: @Norman That was a comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10916445/1338292) and he's right. Instead of ECB you should use CFB, which is also mentioned in this answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hash` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). The `hash_algos()` function returns an array of available algorithms. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php)