# Remember me code not working in my script php

Tags: php, mysql

There are 3 pages in my script
1. header.php
2. auth.php
3. home.php

The header file has the login code and the functions and database connections are in the auth.php.

Now login is working, the only thing is cookie, i mean I want to know how to add a remember function in the script please help.
This is my code
    1. header.php

```
include 'auth.php';
if(empty($_POST['submitlogin']) === false)
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  

if(empty($username) === true)
  {
      $errors[] = '<font color="#FFFFFF">You need to enter an username!</font>';

  } 

 if(empty($password) === true)
  {

      $errors[] = '<font color="#FFFFFF">You need to enter password!</font>';
  } 

else if(user_exists($username) === false )
  {

      if(empty($username) === true){}
      else
        $errors[] = '<font color="#FFFFFF">No such username has been found.</font>';
  } 

else if(user_active($username) === false)
  {

      $errors[] = '<font color="#FFFFFF">You haven\'t activated your account.</font>';
  }
else
  {

    $login = login($username, $password);
    if($login === false)
    {
        $errors[] = '<font color="#FFFFFF">The Username/Password Combination is incorrect</font>';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: home.php');
        exit();
    }
  }
}
```

**2. auth.php code**

```
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

require 'connect.php';


if(logged_in() === true){

  $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password',  'email', 'active', 'type');


  if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false)
    {
      session_destroy(); 
      header('Location: home.php');
      exit();
    }

        }else{

       }

    $errors = array();


  function user_data($user_id)
   {
  $data = array();
  $user_id = (int)$user_id;

  $func_num_args = func_num_args();
  $func_get_args = func_get_args();

  if($func_num_args > 1)
  {
     unset($func_get_args[0]); 

     $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
     $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `edge_users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
     return $data;
  }
   }


   function user_active($username) 
   {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `edge_users` WHERE  `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0)==1)?true: false;  }



    function login($username, $password)
     {
  $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
  $username = sanitize($username);
  $password = md5($password);
  return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `edge_users` WHERE  `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0)  == 1) ? $user_id : false;
      }
```

Html Form

```
  <form  method="post">
  Username
   <input type="text" name="username" style="padding: 5px; width:228px; height:15px;"  autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $_POST['username'];?>"/>>         
   Password
   <input type="password" name="password" style="padding: 5px;  width:228px;height:15px;" />                                                                    
   <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" /> Remember Me  

   <input type="submit" name="submitlogin"  style="background: #00c800; border:1px  solid  #00c800; color:#FFFFFF; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; font-size:14px; float: right;"  value="Login" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Use `$_COOKIE` or `setcookie` if you want more control.

Comment: Could you please guide me where to use?

Comment: Where you set the `$_SESSION` is where you can also set the cookie. P.s. Stackoverflow is meant for questions, not code requests.

Comment: After this line $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;, use setcookie. To retrieve, use $_COOKIE

Comment: Suppose user is checking the remember me checkbox how to save his details and when next time he logins, the password should automatically set without typing

Comment: Don't use `md5()` for password hashing; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using PHP sessions you need to extend the session.

After

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
```

Add the following lines:

```
if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 60*60*24*30, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
}
```

This will extend the PHP session cookie by 30 days if the remember me button is pushed.

On logout you probably want something like this:

```
$_SESSION = array();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
session_destroy();
```

This will destroy your PHP session, so if someone has checked 'Remember me' and logs out and then logs in again without pressing 'Remember me' you do not remember them.