# password not encrypting after using md5() function in php

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, md5

i tried to encrypt passwords for my login using md5() function in php. i followed a tutorial from http://www.phpeasystep.com/workshopview.php?id=26 but the passwords are still readable in my database. i used this code,

```
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="database";
$tbl_name="members";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());

// POST values from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// encrypt password 
$encrypted_password=md5($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$encrypted_password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, password)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Your account had been created..!";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='login.php'>Login to continue</a>";
}

else {
echo "There's an error. Why don't you try again? it may be temporary.";
}
```

please help me...

Comment: Because you're inserting `$password` instead of `$encrypted_password`. That said, you shouldn't use `md5()` for password hashing in the first place; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097#10945097) for more details on hashing and encryption.

Comment: For more background on sensible password hashing see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(name, email, password)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```