# Store login to a 3rd party securly

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I recently came up with a website idea that would require access to a third party site that doesn't have a login api or anything.  I wrote a class that would act as it's api and requires raw login credentials.  So I was wondering what the best way of storing this information is.  I would be running a mysql server and the site will be coded in PHP.  If you have any suggestions please comment!

Thanks.

Comment: if the site is 3rd party, and doesnt have an api or login, how did you write an api for it, this is a bit confusing.  Do you have file access to that site?  I think this would need to be clarified first..

Comment: I said it doesn't have a login api @BrianThomas I managed to send POST data to each individual page.  It's more of a client.  Thanks.

Comment: You mean you're doing this for websites that don't support OAuth?

Comment: Related: [how to encrypt/decrypt data in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php/10945097).

Comment: Yes and thank you, I was already doing that but was just ensuring it's safe @Ja͢ck

Comment: Of course, if your app server is compromised it will be of little use.

Comment: sorry i missed that, so it has an api, just no credential needed right? i.e. free untracked information?