# mysql how to encrypt and decrypt a column using aes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, aes, password-protection, qsqlquery

I have the following the table named MYTABLE with following columns

```
  `idMdP` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

I use it only via PHPMYADMIN.

My aim is to :

- encrypt (AES 256 or AES 512) the password column with a unique key
- using the key to decrypt the column and visualise all columns via a sql query

Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt a password, you should use a password hash function; see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10945097/1338292) [assuming php]

Comment: I think I should use a hash for a traditional php/mysql application because it would be not ehical to know the password of the user based on a single key. But in this case I would like to get a key because all the database is related to my own information and I am the only user. So I dont see why a should use a hash (???).

Comment: Then I don't see why you need encryption either.

Comment: because for instance if someone steal my laptop he will have difficulty to to decrypt my passwords withouth knowing the key

Comment: In case someone steals your laptop you encrypt the file system. Because the encryption key is most likely kept on that same system anyway and unless the key is protected by a password itself you won't see any benefits.