# PHP md5 password not equal to database md5 password

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm having this issue with my login script where the MD5 password stored in my MySQL database is decrypted and it will check if the password is equal to the one entered.

My code is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
 $md5_pass = md5($upass);
 $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 if($row['password'] == $md5_pass)
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
  header("Location: profile.php");
 }
 else
 {  ?>
  <script>alert("Wrong details entered!");</script>
  <?php
 }

}
```

Comment: How do you save new users to the database? And BTW, md5 passwords in your database are not decrypted when you compare them, you just compare hashes.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli` you should arguably also use prepared statements.

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10945097/1338292) and the section on password hashing in particular.

Comment: Btw, you probably should have `$md5_pass = md5($_POST['pass']);`

Comment: @akasummer My passwords are md5 encrypted in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Both the md5() will be same. You must check your column datatype and number of characters limit.

Check whether your database is having encrypted value. Because you are comparing it with `md5()` value.

Comment: The database holds the encrypted password. So, my script will encrypt the password entered by the user and check if the encrypted password is equal to the one in the database

Comment: What is the column datatype and number of characters limit? @BroskyaP

Comment: I'm using varchar(50) @AnkiiGangrade

Comment: can you `echo` and paste these 2 variables : `$row['password']` and `$md5_pass`?

Comment: only returns the `$md5_pass`, which returns: `cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5`

Comment: What result you get when you `print_r($row);` before `if` condition?

Comment: Nothing happens @AnkiiGangrade

Comment: That means the email id does not exist in your database. You should check number of rows also before `if` like `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($res);` @BroskyaP

Comment: I ran the query with the `email="myemail"` in phpMyAdmin and it worked fine

Comment: @BroskyaP : Use like this : `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'"; $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` Also echo `$sql` and check that query.

Comment: The `echo $sql` gives me the right values. But, the login in general still does not work

Comment: If your query is right then why you are not getting anything in when you print `print_r($row);`? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Apparently I had error reporting turned off, right now the error is `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` while I'm passing it `$res` which is the result?

Comment: Is `$con` a valid connection?

Comment: It should be, it is defined in the connection file as `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }`

Comment: Have to used `mysqli_select_db($con,"DATABASENAME");` ?

Comment: Tried that before, but apparently it works this time! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape before performing md5 on the query.

Ankii's reply can also solve the issue if you have a varchar which is too small.

Also, use a better hashing system (sha512?).
Also, use salt.

Comment: The better hashing system is either bcrypt, scrypt, or some kind of KDF as last resort.

Comment: Hey @Ja͢ck, I'll be sure to use that at a later stage!