# OpenSSL or Mcrypt? (openssl_encrypt or mcrypt_encrypt)

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I guess it's a question of pros & cons.

For simple data crypting:

What are the real benefits of using `openssl_encrypt` over `mcrypt_encrypt`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667

Comment: Also see [Upgrading my encryption library from Mcrypt to OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43329513/608639) and [Preparing for removal of Mcrypt in PHP 7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42696657/608639)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Don't use mcrypt**. If you're typing the word mcrypt into your code, you're probably making a mistake. Although it's possible to provide a relatively secure cryptography library that builds on top of mcrypt (the earlier version of defuse/php-encryption did), switching your code to openssl will provide better security, performance, maintainability, and portability.
[source: paragonie.com](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

**Speed** openssl is faster. Take a look at the following table [source: jrm.cc](https://jrm.cc/posts/php-aes-openssl/)

```
# php examples/compare.php
Results:
+---------+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| ext     | keylen | textsize | (en/de)code | ops/sec      |
+---------+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| mcrypt  |    128 | short    | enc         |   5626.38872 |
| mcrypt  |    128 | short    | dec         |   5729.21909 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | short    | enc         |   5694.37256 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | short    | dec         |   5682.78434 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | short    | enc         |   5644.36358 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | short    | dec         |   5661.23080 |
| mcrypt  |    128 | medium   | enc         |   5583.97725 |
| mcrypt  |    128 | medium   | dec         |   5650.75122 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | medium   | enc         |   5591.54051 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | medium   | dec         |   5552.83950 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | medium   | enc         |   5524.18533 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | medium   | dec         |   5513.65563 |
| mcrypt  |    128 | long     | enc         |   4773.67544 |
| mcrypt  |    128 | long     | dec         |   4774.14273 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | long     | enc         |   4633.75035 |
| mcrypt  |    192 | long     | dec         |   4634.35450 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | long     | enc         |   4494.90529 |
| mcrypt  |    256 | long     | dec         |   4280.92422 |
| openssl |    128 | short    | enc         | 168581.35048 |
| openssl |    128 | short    | dec         | 170417.03234 |
| openssl |    192 | short    | enc         | 172052.83452 |
| openssl |    192 | short    | dec         | 171349.94689 |
| openssl |    256 | short    | enc         | 171112.27154 |
| openssl |    256 | short    | dec         | 171644.45899 |
| openssl |    128 | medium   | enc         | 166944.11718 |
| openssl |    128 | medium   | dec         | 169084.25381 |
| openssl |    192 | medium   | enc         | 166665.50107 |
| openssl |    192 | medium   | dec         | 168459.47466 |
| openssl |    256 | medium   | enc         | 163878.40900 |
| openssl |    256 | medium   | dec         | 167946.82470 |
| openssl |    128 | long     | enc         | 110370.61207 |
| openssl |    128 | long     | dec         | 142731.36868 |
| openssl |    192 | long     | enc         | 103798.85171 |
| openssl |    192 | long     | dec         | 135396.21667 |
| openssl |    256 | long     | enc         |  96767.81100 |
| openssl |    256 | long     | dec         | 132203.99672 |
+---------+--------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

**Abandonware** mcrypt is basically abandonware. So, especially if you're starting from scratch (or as a [php.net comment states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667) *you are writing code in 2015*), do it right . Go with OpenSSL. [source: stackoverflow Artjom B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324382/2119863)