# Encoding, Decoding by secret key

Tags: php, function, cookies, encoding, decoding

If I have this cookie:

```
$my_cookie = "value";
```

And i would like to encode this value by secret key like this:

```
$encode_cookie = encoding($my_cookie, "key");
setcookie('my_cookie',$encode_cookie);
```

Then,  I use way like this way to get the value of cookie:

```
$my_cookie = decoding($encode_cookie, "key");
```

So, Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a symmetric encryption to be able to encrypt and then decrypt with the same key.

Take a look at : http://php.net/mcrypt-encrypt