# PHP: obfuscate PHP output?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to obfuscate the PHP output (html stuff).

basically, I have a few hidden inputs and they have some PHP outputs in them...

Example:

`<input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>" />`

is there any way to obfuscate its value in the users browser but still readable server side so I can pass the input value between pages?

any suggestion and help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:
I did it like this:**

```
$string = "my string to be be encrypted goes here";
$secret_key = "This is my secret key";

// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// Decrypt $string
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo "Original string : " . $string . "<br />\n";
echo "Encrypted string : " . $encrypted_string . "<br />\n";
echo "Decrypted string : " . $decrypted_string . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: Why not encrypt the value on on1 page and decrypt on the other page?

Comment: @Daan, i did look into that and the only thing I came across was `md5()` which would make it impossible to `decrypt` it once its been `encrypted`! any suggestions?

Comment: `md5()` is a hashing function. Hashing isn't encryption.

Comment: You can use base64 encoding with any other cipher (md5 is one way algorithm). But why not using php sessions if both scripts are on the same machine?

Comment: @Daan, got ya... I think I've sorted it now with your suggestion. sweet.

Comment: @rooz Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php) for info on doing actual encryption in PHP

Comment: @jDo, cheers. I edited my question.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I don't think i need a class. check out the code posted in my question.

Comment: Was just a comment that it works and is very effective. Wasn't saying you need a class :)

Comment: @RyanVincent, okay mate. Thank you.

Comment: If you aren't wanting people to know the actual value, or tamper with it, why not store it in the session?

Comment: @gabe3886, I am storing what i can in the `$_SESSION[''];`. However, what I'm trying to do is out of the scope of sessions thus using hidden inputs. anyway, with a bit of decryption and encryption, it works like a charm.

Comment: I have the impression that you are asking how to use a shoe to drive a nail because that's out of the scope of hammers... You cannot use sessions to e.g. share values between different computers or browsers, but regular forms can't either.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the values as part of the form field; do not send them data at all! Save the data to a database table and link to the current user. Link the data with the user via any number of methods (User id, cookie, session, etc). when the form is submitted retrieve the `secret` and execute your business logic.

**Side note**: If you want the data to be secure you want to encrypt it, not hash, not encode; encrypt.