# How to encrypt fields in a database with PHP in 2016?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I know this question has been asked before, but the most recent answer I found was [here in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php), now 4 years ago. I know encryption changes, so what are the current encryption algorithms - or PHP commands - to encrypt fields?

Is there a website that would have this info, and which I could check in the future?

Edit: This is different from the question it's marked as a duplicate of because that question was asking about mysql encryption and this one is about PHP encryption. I know I caused the confusion by mistakenly linking the wrong question, but I've fixed the link to prevent further confusion.

I also found out the answer: PHP has built-in encryption algorithms that it updates with new versions.

On the more general note of what encryption algorithms are appropriate for use today: [NIST's list of approved algorithms](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf) updates every few years and includes only publicly-vetted algorithms. And since writing this question, I've learned that even if using the most up-to-date algorithms, you should not implement your own (i.e. write your own code), you should instead use a crypto library. So this information is only useful for ruling out libraries/products.

Comment: If you want new answers add a bounty to that older question

Comment: @JohnConde The other question is closed as off-topic. Getting new answers would require reopening it.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Then this one would be off-topic, too. No?

Comment: Nothing changed. 256 bit AES is still in the playing field.

Comment: @JohnConde Categorically, yes. I was just pointing out: Aside from the fact that adding a bounty isn't something a user with only 37 rep can really do, that would require reversing the previous decision to close the other thread to get new answers.

Comment: I actually linked the wrong SO answer - fixed now. The question then is whether, if I'm using PHP-embedded or OpenSSL functions, they'll be be up-to-date.