# Visitors IP Address in database

Tags: php, database, security, encryption, ip

I have a question if I should somehow encrypt (secure) the IP address of the user that I put in the database? If yes, then how should I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Click here solution http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

It is unnecessary to encrypt the IP address. IP addresses are public knowledge and usually obfuscated by the ISP anyway. The best someone would get out of an IP address is a city. And that's assuming they don't use proxies or VPNs.

If you do need to encrypt some data such as SSN, DOB, DL#, or CC# (hopefully you are storing tokens instead of actual CC#) then see this post: [How to encrypt/decrypt data in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916284/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-php)

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer.