# Store encrypted password in mysql and decrypt while fetching

Tags: java, mysql, sql, des, password-encryption

I am using `DES_ENCRYPT` method to store password to MySQL. This is working, but when I retrieve by `DES_DECRYPT` I get the HTML character references for certain symbols. For example I stored `&` by encrypting, but while decrypting I get `&amp;`. How to handle this so that I only get `&` after decryption and not `&amp;` If there is any other better direct method i can use that but in either case I need the real password stored.

Comment: 1.) WHY DO YOU STORE ENCRYPTED PASSWORDS? DON'T DO THAT! 2.) I'm *pretty* sure that those functions *don't* do anything with HTML entities, that problem must be at some other point.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287517/encrypting-hashing-plain-text-passwords-in-database

Comment: You probably are HTML encoding the password when printing it, but like @Joachim says it is not a problem with those function. And like Joachim says, never store encrypted passwords, the passwords must be stored in a way that nobody (neither you) can't decrypt them.

Comment: I did the following query `insert into users (emailid,password) values ('abc@gmail.com', DES_ENCRYPT('ad2*(&8ev'))` which stores the password as `€o'ù…G9xo9IuÑf` and when i make the following query `SELECT DES_DECRYPT(password) FROM 'users'` i get `ad2*(&amp;8ev` which is not same as the original one which is encrypted.

Comment: I need this for running a cron job which requires password for authentication

Comment: `SELECT DES_DECRYPT(DES_ENCRYPT('ad2*(&8ev'))` this returns `ad2*(&8ev`, so it kinda gets demonstrated that the problem must be in another place, as @JoachimSauer and @artberri pointed.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I am using `lampp` in linux system. I again ran the same query you wrote in `phpmyadmin` but it gives me `ad2*(&amp;8ev`. Any idea where might be the problem?

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is probably html-encoding the html entities before showing them. If you look at the source code, the `&` appears as `&amp;`, but this is done to prevent XSS attacks. If you are somehow parsing the html phpmyadmin is outputting (why the hell would you do that??), you need to call an html decoding function like the proposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Carlos said `phpmyadmin` is probably html-encoding the html entities before showing is true. This is true. There is no problem with the function. When i decrypt from outside `phpmyadmin` the password is decrypted properly. I made the mistake earlier i tried to directly do it from the admin panel and now i am running it from the script outside the admin panel.