# Securely storing passwords on MongoDB + Python

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku

I have a MongoDB running on Heroku, and I need to store full credentials for a 3rd party API, including password, username, security token, etc.

What is the best way to protect the data?

Would appreciate code samples in raw python (no Framework used for this one).

Thanks

**Update** - forgot to mention that I am storing credentials for many users, so this is why I'm looking at a database-solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the `heroku config` command line utility? I found that to be the best solution for storing sensitive data, I use it for AWS keys and PostgreSQL logins.

The general approach is this:

```
$ heroku config:set DBUSERNAME=value DBPASSWORD=value
$ heroku config
DBUSERNAME: value
DBPASSWORD: value
# you should see you all your environment variables
```

When you have them setup, inside your Python file, just fetch your `environ` dictionary:

```
import os
print os.environ.get('DBUSERNAME', None) // should print "value"
```

And there you go. You can read more on how to use the `config` utility by entering this into the terminal:

```
$ heroku help config
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the credentials I store are for multiple users, this is why I'm looking at a database-based solution

Comment: @AviMeir well that ruins 5 minutes of my work... Well in that case, use PostgreSQL or whatever to store them, there is nothing exceptional about that.

Comment: My question still stands, what would you use to securely store the passwords and tokens? hashing of some kind?

Comment: Yeah, hashing + random salt methods are the go to ways for storing passwords, you shoud definitely read this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287517/encrypting-hashing-plain-text-passwords-in-database.