# Can't login from my Android app using HttpPost

Tags: java, php, android

The php code

```
$userName=$_POST['userName'];
$userPassword=$_POST['userPassword'];
.
.
$result=MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE UserName='$userName' and   Password='$userPassword' ");

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_start();
$_SESSION["userName"] = "$userName";
echo 1;
header('Location: http://www.naviwi.com/points.php');
}
else {
header('Location: http://www.naviwi.com/signUp.php');
}
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

The java code. I get the username and password values from two TexitEdit IO.

```
public void userLogin(View view){


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://naviwi.com/checkLogin");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userPassword", password));
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            et.append("UnsupportedEncodingException");
        }

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            et.append("Server not Responding"+ response);
        }

        et.append(" Server respond "+response);
    }
```

So the problem is that I always get null. I want to get the 1 from the response method in PHP.

Comment: yet another NOMTE ... please at least do e.printStackTrace() at catch to see what error you are getting

Comment: Where can I find the result of this call. Im using android studio.

Comment: Is this correct `new HttpPost("http://naviwi/checkLogin")`?

Comment: no It should be .com. But still not working :(

Comment: @Zhexa What do you mean by "not working"? What is this supposed to do? Because you are simply doing nothing with the response.

Comment: I want to know from the server if the login data is valid.

Comment: @Zhexa So you have to update you PHP script to return such information (for example, return a JSON) instead of just doing a HTTP redirect to a HTML page.

Comment: The code I use in eclipse works with echo. When I move it to android Studio its no longer working. I tried to add JSON but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query is using a wrong field. The password field is called 'userPassword', so you query should be

```
$result=MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE UserName='$userName' and   userPassword='$userPassword' ");
```

WARNING: You're storing clear text passwords on your database and this is a really bad practice. You should [hash them with a salt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287517/encrypting-hashing-plain-text-passwords-in-database)

Comment: The php is working when I access it from my webpage. In my database its Password not userPassword, so this is not the bug.

Comment: try this `  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));`